# Who can explain how this code is not an error?

Tags: python, function, return, fractals

I was making some exercise to train myself and the exercise asked me to do a program that calculates fractals, very simple, i've done in about 1-2 minutes and it work, but looking at his solution it return x multiplicated by the function itself? how does this run? I know maybe it's a stupid question but i think it might be useful.

```
def fract(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    return x * fract(x - 1)

print(fract(int(input())))
```

Comment: Look up "recursive functions".

Comment: Add a print(x) statement before the if statement and re-run the code. It might be very descriptive for you.

Comment: That's a function call. It works the same way any other function call works. Why do you think it's a problem that it's calling the same function?

Comment: recursive: _(adj.)_ see **recursive**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a walk through of whats going on.

First, you call fract(int(input())). The input method gets a response from the user and parses that to an int. and then calls fract on that int.

Say we enter 3. So our print statement evaluates to fract(3).

fract(3) returns 3 * fract(2)
fract(2) is called and that returns 2 * fract(1)
fract(1) is called and that returns 1

So putting it altogether and substituting function calls for what they return we get fract(3) returns 3 * (2 * (1)).

Comment: Okk so putting it in little terms it's like a mini loop, cool

Comment: @Pingu: In fact, it's how loops are done in functional programming.

Comment: @Pingu This might be beyond the scope of what you're looking for, but you should be careful with recursive methods. It's easier to end up with an infinite loop if you haven't taken care of the base case.

Comment: @KrabbyPatty: Also, there's a risk of crashing the program due to excessive stack depth even with properly limited recursion, especially in languages that don't have tail call optimization (such as CPython).